# Does anyone know if you use Spring security, do you have to use taglib?

Tags: oauth, jaxb, spring-security, cxf, taglib

I am trying to use OAuth for spring security with CXF. But the example only provides things with jsp, and taglib, I am not really experienced with jsp, I just want to serve entities using JaxB with OAuth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't need to use the taglib. It's quite common, for example, for people to use [authorization via method interceptors](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html#ns-method-security) alone; however, going the non-web route will typically require some custom coding or more in-depth knowledge of how to set up the framework, so that you can do things like pass user authentication credentials properly.

Just make sure to differentiate between the [taglib](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/taglibs.html) (JSP tag library, used for in-page authorization checks, etc.), and the [XML namespace configuration](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html), which you *may* need to ease setup.